# Visual Studio C++ compiler options: Why does /O2 define /Gs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The Visual Studio C++ compiler option [/O2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f8h5cxt.aspx) (maximize speed) is equivalent to

```
/Og /Oi /Ot /Oy /Ob2 /Gs /GF /Gy
```

Why [/Gs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9598wk25%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? How does it help maximize speed? (Note that it is [/Gs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9598wk25%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), not [/GS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dbf701c.aspx).)

Comment: For anyone else who had to google it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9598wk25(v=vs.80).aspx  Definitely sounds odd to me that it would enable it...

Comment: @Corbin: Thanks. I have added the link to the question.

Comment: Just noticed that it's the link to VS 2005, but shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**/O2 doesn't set /Gs, it's an error in the documentation.**

Some experimentation (it's easy to see the __chkstk calls in the generated assembly) shows that:

/Gs (with no number) is equivalent to /Gs0 and means always insert __chkstk calls. And indeed, the MSDN says the same:

> If the /Gs option is specified without a size argument, it is the same as     specifying /Gs0,

/O2 does *not* set /Gs (aka /Gs0), there's a clear difference between "/O2" and "/O2 /Gs". Although it's possible it changes the default to something other than the page it seems more likely that this is just a documentation bug.

Stack probes are never good for performance, it only has a job to do when the stack is advancing to a new high water mark and is wasted cycles the rest of the time. This means that if you have a loop that calls a function 100 times, that functions stack probe *might* grow the stack the first time, but other 99 times it doesn't change anything because the stack was already grown the first time - if it needed to be grown at all.

Answer (score 13):

/Gs will insert stack probes in functions that use more than one page (4kB typically) of local variables. A stack probe signals to the OS that you'll use a lot of stack space. If this probe hits the guard page, the OS knows that it will need to allocate an extra page of RAM for the stack to grow.

This is an optimization, because without the probe the actual memory access would trigger the RAM allocation, and the function would stall until the RAM is allocated. The probe, as part of the function prolog, doesn't cause a stall (at least not as severe).

[edit]
Another benefit is that a stack probe up front will allocate memory once. If you need 16 KB of stack space and rely on allocation-on-demand, you'll have 4 page faults that each grow the stack by 4 KB. A single probe can replace these 4 faults with one syscall.

Comment: Looks like for Visual Studio 2013 they defaulted `/Gs` with no provided value to => `/Gs0` - i.e. do stack probes always. I'm not sure how this interacts with `/O2` any more, the docs for which seem to imply that it just sets `/Gs` (so presumably => `/Gs0`)

Comment: @AlastairMaw: My reading is that `/Gs` and `/Gs0` are synonyms, but that the default is in fact `/Gs4096`.

Comment: If that's the case then your answer read literally here is wrong - adding `/Gs` by itself will insert stack probes in *all* functions. The docs prior to the 2013 version are unclear what the default value is if you specify `/Gs` with no value. Is it 0 or is it the default 4096 (which would effectively change nothing over omitting the switch entirely)? It seems odd that `/O2` would deliberately change this to a value of 0, which will reduce performance.

Comment: @AlastairMaw: A stack probe costs code space, but may prevent a CPU page fault later on. The effect on performance probably variew between programs. If I understand Windows correctly, there's only a single guard page. Therefore you generally need a stack probe for functions with more than 4096 bytes of stack space. Accessing the last local variable first could jump over the 4K guard page. That's why there's a `/Gs4096` default - it's needed for correctness in large functions. Any smaller value, such as  `/Gs0` is done in the hope that it saves time in page faults, but no guarantees here.